# When I using node-alpine with docker it does not work properly

Tags: docker

I am very new to Docker. I have created Dockerfile. It looks like this.

```
FROM node:10.9.0-alpine
```

When I hit the command to build the docker image it gives me an error saying that

```
manifest for node:10.9.0-alpine not found
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?  Thank you!!

Comment: hmm `node:10.9.o-alpine not found` this looks like the letter `o` and not like `0`

Comment: I have edit the question

Comment: have you tried to pull first the image?

Comment: What do you mean by "When I hit the command to build the docker image"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a timing or build issue when the latest image is being updated due to a pull request.

https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/3835

There is an issue where the image is posted a ready because other architectures are already built but the build you want could take up to an extra hour.

Try again in 5 minutes, it usually resolves itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's working.

Can you check whether your docker daemon is able to pull images from docker-registry ?

For that try removing hello-world image from your downloaded images by executing following command and then retry it to download again.

```
$ docker rmi hello-world
$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
9db2ca6ccae0: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:4b8ff392a12ed9ea17784bd3c9a8b1fa3299cac44aca35a85c90c5e3c7afacdc
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/
```

If above command works fine then below command will also work fine.

```
$ docker pull node:10.9.0-alpine
10.9.0-alpine: Pulling from library/node
8e3ba11ec2a2: Downloading [===========>                                       ]  490.2kB/2.207MB
0cbaf23af500: Downloading [=>                                                 ]  441.1kB/21.4MB
c53714e0a6af: Downloading [====================>                              ]  450.6kB/1.078MB
```

Comment: It worked correctly. But when I try to pull node image it gives me an error  now it looks this _no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries_

Comment: The suggested fix did not work and this wasn't answered

Answer (score -1):

Please try some other node image version
I used node:10-jessie image and didn't get the issue again

Comment: Using a completely different architecture is possible, but what if the OP wants to use Alpine, and not Debian?